# Tensorflow: learn evaluation of boolean features

Tags: input, tensorflow, boolean

I want to train a model with tensorflow that has boolean features like this:

```
data = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]], dtype=bool)

target = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5], dtype=np.int )
```

Looks like an easy task to me, but it turns out, it is no easy task for me. I have no idea how to do this, can not find anything similar (besides [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443395/read-boolean-features-for-tensorflow) ) on the web and I am not able to adjust one of the tensorflow examples to my needs.

O.K. Here comes the code...

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function


import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import collections

# Data sets
dataComplete = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[0,1,1],[1,0,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,0],[1,1,1]], dtype=bool)
targetComplete = np.array([0,     1,      2,      3,      4,      5,      6,      7     ], dtype=np.int )

Dataset = collections.namedtuple('Dataset', ['data', 'target'])

# for trainig data, remove some data from the complete set
data = np.delete(dataComplete, [2,4,6], 0)
target = np.delete(targetComplete, [2,4,6])
training_set = Dataset(data=data, target=target)

# for test set pick some of the complete set.
data = np.array([[0,1,0], [1,0,0]], dtype=bool)
target = np.array([2,4], dtype=np.int )
test_set = Dataset(data=data, target=target)


# Specify that all features have real-value data 
# <-- This is seems to be wrong. I do not have a real valued featured, but boolean features. However
# I could not something like tf.contrib.layers.boolean_valued_column
feature_columns = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("", dimension=3)]


# Build 3 layer DNN with 10, 20, 10 units respectively.
#classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
#                                            hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
#                                            n_classes=8,
#                                            model_dir="/tmp/chesspositions_model")
classifier = tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier(feature_columns)

# Fit model.
classifier.fit(x=training_set.data,
               y=training_set.target,
               steps=100)

# Evaluate accuracy.
accuracy_score = classifier.evaluate(x=test_set.data,
                                     y=test_set.target)["accuracy"]

print('Accuracy: {0:f}'.format(accuracy_score))
```

1. Running this code as shown yields an Accuracy: 0.000000
2. When I use data in test_set that are contained in training_set (e.g.   `data = np.array([[0,0,1], [0,1,1]], dtype=bool); target = np.array([1,3], dtype=np.int)`) I get an Accuracy: 0.500000
3. When I exchange the LinearClassifier with a DNNClassifier (see comments in code), I get Accuracy: 0.000000 for the disjunct test_set (see 1.)
4. For contained test_set (see 2.) I get Accuracy: 1.000000

I do not understand these results :-o
I had expected an Accuracy of some 0.something on first step that increases with each step to approach an Accuracy of 1.0. And I expected this approach to be slower for disjunct trainings- and test-set.

The parameter `steps=1` in `classifier.fit` does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: please post some of the tensorflow code, what have you triied?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.